# How to check if every two flipped cards' current title of their buttons in an array are matching in a card matching game

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding in some functionalities for this iOS swift matching card game and I need to check if the first 2 buttons flipped over match. They have four types of emojis for eight cards, which means there are 4 pairs of matches. I am having trouble finding out how to check if the cards match and when they match, I need the background color of the buttons to opaque (invisible). Everything else works except the empty if statement in the concentration class within the chooseCard function. That is where I need help.
Here's all the code so you can see whats related to what:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var game = Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: (cardButtons.count + 1) / 2)

    var flipCount = 0 {
        // Property Observer
        didSet { flipLabel.text = "Flips: \(flipCount)" }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var flipLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]!

    @IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flipCount+=1
        if let cardNumber = cardButtons.firstIndex(of: sender) {
            game.chooseCard(at: cardNumber)
            updateViewFromModel()
        } else {
            print ("chosen card was not in cardButtons")
        }

    }

    var emojiChoices = ["", "", "", ""]

    var emoji = [Int:String]()

    func emoji(for card: Card) -> String {
       if emoji[card.identifier] == nil, emojiChoices.count > 0 {
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(emojiChoices.count)))
        emoji[card.identifier] = emojiChoices.remove(at: randomIndex)

        }
        return emoji[card.identifier] ?? "?"
    }

    func updateViewFromModel() {
        for index in cardButtons.indices {
            let button = cardButtons[index]
            let card = game.cards[index]
            if card.isFaceUp  {
                button.setTitle(emoji(for: card), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }
            else {
                button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            }

        }
    }
}
```

import Foundation

```
class Concentration {

    var cards = [Card]()

    func chooseCard(at index: Int) {
        if cards[index].isFaceUp {
            cards[index].isFaceUp = false
        }
        else {
            cards[index].isFaceUp = true
        }

        if cards[index].isFaceUp && cards[index].isMatched {

        }
    }

    init(numberOfPairsOfCards: Int) {
        for _ in 0..<numberOfPairsOfCards {
        let card = Card()
        cards += [card,card]
        }

        //TODO: Shuffle cards
        cards.shuffle()
    }
}

import Foundation

struct Card {
    var isMatched = false
    var isFaceUp = false
    var identifier: Int

    static var identifierFactory = 0

    static func getUniqueIdentifier() -> Int {
        Card.identifierFactory += 1
        return Card.identifierFactory
    }

    init() {
        self.identifier = Card.getUniqueIdentifier()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code as text. Use code formatting from the toolbar

Comment: @Paulw11 This is the code i am stuck on. I updated the question

Comment: please post code instead of Screenshots

Comment: You need something in your `Card` struct that you can match against. Ie your two matching cards must have some property in common and then you just compare the two selected cards using this property.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure how to reference the button titles because that is the only difference in the buttons. This is my first swift project and my instructor coded all but a few parts on this. I am a complete beginner so I'm not sure how to reference specific things in swift, especially from different files.

Comment: The emoji should be a property of the card not determine by your view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your concentration class you will check for faceUp card indexes

Change your Concentration from class to Struct

```
struct Concentration { // instead of class Concentration

private var indexOfFaceUpCard: Int? {
        get {
            let faceUpCardIndices = cards.indices.filter { cards[$0].isFaceUp }
            return faceUpCardIndices.count == 1 ? faceUpCardIndices.first : nil
        } set {
            for index in cards.indices {
                cards[index].isFaceUp = (index == newValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you have mutating chooseCard method

```
mutating func chooseCard(at index: Int)
```

In your chooseCard method you check for matching

```
if !cards[index].isMatched {
            if let matchIndex = indexOfFaceUpCard, matchIndex != index {
                if cards[matchIndex] == cards[index] {
                    cards[matchIndex].isMatched = true
                    cards[index].isMatched = true
                }
                cards[index].isFaceUp = true

            } else {
                indexOfFaceUpCard = index
            }
        }
```

So your method look like this

```
mutating func chooseCard(at index: Int) {

        if !cards[index].isMatched {
            if let matchIndex = indexOfFaceUpCard, matchIndex != index {
                if cards[matchIndex] == cards[index] {
                    cards[matchIndex].isMatched = true
                    cards[index].isMatched = true
                }
                cards[index].isFaceUp = true

            } else {
                indexOfFaceUpCard = index
            }
        }
}
```

Update your card struct

```
struct Card: Hashable {
    var isMatched = false
    var isFaceUp = false
    var identifier: Int

    static var identifierFactory = 0

    static func getUniqueIdentifier() -> Int {
        Card.identifierFactory += 1
        return Card.identifierFactory
    }
  static func ==(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
      return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
  }

    init() {
        self.identifier = Card.getUniqueIdentifier()
    }
}
```

Comment: anytime I've tried to use mutating it gives me the error :mutating' isn't valid on methods in classes or class-bound protocols

Comment: mutating is applicable on value typed ... class is reference type ... so change your concentration from class to struct ... updated my answer

Comment: thanks! Also, where you have stoppTime() i get the error use of unresolved identifier.  and on the next line it says Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Card' operands

Comment: removed timer ... it was my fault

Comment: That makes sense i was just reading up on that. Thanks a lot i had no idea I was that far off.

Comment: will def do. Just curious, is there a way to pull the background attribute into the concentration struc?

Comment: in your controller ... function ... updateViewmodal ... handle it there

Comment: func updateViewModel() {
       for index in cardButtons.indices {
           let button = cardButtons[index]
           let card = game.cards[index]
           if card.isFaceUp {
               button.setTitle(emoji(for: card), for: .normal)
               button.backgroundColor = .white
               button.isEnabled = false
           } else {
               button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = card.isMatched ? UIColor.red : UIColor.green
               button.isEnabled = true
           }
       }
   }

Comment: oh okay that worked. I tried that earlier but didn't have the matching check down. Thanks so much. Is there a way to give you like a special review ? This was a life saver.

Comment: `Hashable` doesn’t imply `Equatable`. You got `==` to work because you implemented this operator yourself. With that, you could drop the `Hashable` conformance and it would still work. But if you conformed to `Equatable`, you could drop the `==` function in `Card`, since compiler will generate this for `struct`s.